# appending underscores between substrings

Tags: string, algorithm

You are given a main string and a substring and you need to append _ at the start and end of that substring. The one thing to note is if the substring comes together you need to append _ between the first and last instance and same is true if the string overlap.

eg:

```
input - main String - testabctesttestdeftestestestxyz
        substring - test

output - _test_abc_testtest_def_testestest_xyz
```

Comment: What programming language are you using, and what have you tried so far?  If this be a homework question, then are you limited to solving it using only certain methods?

Answer (score 1):

the idea is like:

1. first find all indexes of the sub-string from the original string. the catch here, some sub-string may be formed as continues (eg. testestest).
2. to get continues words' indexes, you have to check which indexes are overlapping or short by 1. eg - for your input 7 to 14 and 18 to 27 are overlapping.

> [[0, 3], [7, 10], [11, 14], [18, 21], [21, 24], [24, 27]]

3. now you can merge those overlapped indexes.

> [[0, 3], [7, 14], [18, 27]]

4. once you merge them, done! : )
5. now you can put underscore, in-between the string, according to tofinal indexes!

Since you did not mention any programming language, I'm attaching java code here!

function for getting indexes of the substring from the original string and store indexes on a list:

```
 void checkAndAdd(String s, String t, int index, List<List<Integer>> list) {
    boolean flag = true;
    int len = (s.length() > t.length()) ? t.length() : s.length();
    s = s.substring(index);
    int i, n = t.length();
    /* traverse whole substring, if n (denotes - substring's length) becomes
      0 -- means "substring found" */
    /* if so, add starting index and last index into a list as first_index and 
     last_index*/
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(i)) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }else n--;
    }
    if(flag && n == 0) {
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        temp.add(index); // start index
        temp.add(i+index-1); // end index
        list.add(temp);
    }
}
```

now you have to check which indexes are overlapping if you find any such indexes just merge them:

```
  void overlappingCloseIndexes(List<List<Integer>> list) {
    int i;      
    for(i=1; i<list.size(); i++) {

        List<Integer> prev = list.get(i-1);
        List<Integer> next = list.get(i);
        /* merge overlapped indexes */
        if(next.get(0) - prev.get(1) == 1 || next.get(0) - prev.get(1) == 0) {
            int last = next.get(1);             
            list.remove(i);
            prev.remove(1);
            prev.add(last);
        }
    }
    List<Integer> prev = list.get(list.size()-2);
    List<Integer> next = list.get(list.size()-1);

    if(next.get(0) - prev.get(1) == 1 || next.get(0) - prev.get(1) == 0) {
        int last = next.get(1);             
        list.remove(list.size()-1);
        prev.remove(1);
        prev.add(last);
    }
}
```

at the last, you can append "_" before and after the indexes (which are substring index):

```
 String append(String s, List<List<Integer>> list) {
    int first = list.get(0).get(0), last = list.get(0).get(1);
    list.remove(0);
    String temp = "";
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        // append "_" whenever i == first_index or i == last_index 
        if(i == first) {
            temp += "_";
        }else if(i == last+1){
            temp += "_";
            if(!list.isEmpty()) {
                first = list.get(0).get(0);
                last = list.get(0).get(1);

                list.remove(0);
            }
        }
        temp += s.charAt(i);

    }
    if(i == last+1) {
        temp +="_";
    }
    return temp;
}
```

here is the driver function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "testabctesttestdeftestestestxyz";
    String t = "test";
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) == t.charAt(0)) {
            /* check whenever i-th char from main string match 
             0-th char of substring */
            checkAndAdd(s, t, i, list);
        }
    }
    overlappingCloseIndexes(list);
    s = append(s, list);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

NOTE: to find substring index from main-string requires O(n^2) complexity, and this is the overall complexity of this program!